# Vue : Conditional render of div based on v-if, But i dont want to show the div if it returns null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following html with conditional render using v-if

```
    <div v-if="showdiv">
        <p>Content 1 here</p>
    </div>
    <div v-if="!showdiv">
        <p>Content 2 here</p>
    </div>
```

In data variable I have set

```
data() {
  render {
     showdiv: ''
  }
}
```

So I have an api, whose response decides whether showdiv is false or true. But sometimes api is slow, then the value of showdiv should be null and none of the div must be shown, But in my case showdiv is taken as false and this get displayed

```
    <div v-if="!showdiv">
        <p>Content 2 here</p>
    </div>
```

I dont want both the divs to be displayed when the value is null.I only want to render the div if its true or false, in other cases let it not show. What i can do to achieve that ?

Comment: Have an `isLoading` flag and show loading when it is true and when it is false only then render your other divs.

Comment: @UtsavPatel I dont want to set a loader for this api too as page takes too long to load if i have to wait for this api, I have loader in place already for the basic details to get loaded. I only want to render the div if its true or false, in other cases let it not show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check explicitly if the `typeof showdiv` is `boolean` or not and based on that show the divs like:

```
<div v-if="typeof showdiv === 'boolean' && showdiv">
  <p>Content 1 here</p>
</div>
<div v-if="typeof showdiv === 'boolean' && !showdiv">
  <p>Content 2 here</p>
</div>
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: {
    showdiv: ''
  },
  async mounted() {
    // wait for 2 second
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    this.showdiv = true;
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="myApp">
  <div>
    <p>The content divs will show after few seconds . . .</p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="typeof showdiv === 'boolean' && showdiv">
    <p>Content 1 here</p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="typeof showdiv === 'boolean' && !showdiv">
    <p>Content 2 here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @palash It is working, Is it possible to avoid the <template> tag and write the detailed if condition for both the <div> tags ?

Comment: Not getting what you mean here exactly. Can you share an example? I get that you want to remove the template tag. But where you want to put the condition?

Comment: Can i put the condition in both the div, one in which now we presently have given v-if="showdiv"  and another one in which we have v-if="!showdiv"

Comment: Yes, that is also possible. I have added logic for it.

Comment: Thanks it works, I added your first logic like this v-if="showdiv && showdiv !==''" and v-if="!showdiv && showdiv !==''", and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

try like this:

```
<div v-if="showdiv === true">
  <p>Content 1 here</p>
</div>
<div v-if="showdiv === false">
    <p>Content 2 here</p>
</div>
```